# CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a class named Player ... in the init method I want to use a CCSpriteBatchNode:

```
@interface Player : CCNode {

    CCSprite *player;
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet;
    CCAction *walkAction;
    int playerSpeed;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *player;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAction *walkAction;

@property int playerSpeed;

@property int xPos;

@property int yPos;


-(id)init {

    if( (self=[super init] )) {

        playerSpeed = 70;
        xPos = 160;
        yPos = 10;
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"bugA.plist"];
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"bugA.png"];
        [player useBatchNode:spriteSheet];
        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8 ; ++i) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bug%d.png", i]]];
        }
        CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
        player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bug1.png"];
        walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
        [player runAction:walkAction];

        [spriteSheet addChild:player];
    }
    return self;
}
```

then in HelloWorldScene I want to use this class with animation

```
Player *pl = [Player node];

[self addChild:pl.player];
```

but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here your code with some modification

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"bugA.plist"];
spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"bugA.png"];

//add :
[self addChild:spriteSheet];

//instead of :
[player useBatchNode:spriteSheet];

NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 1; i <= 8 ; ++i) {
    [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bug%d.png", i]]];
}
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.1f];
player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bug1.png"];

//add to show the player in the middle of the screen
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
player.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);       

walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
[player runAction:walkAction];

[spriteSheet addChild:player];
```

To use this code just call

```
Player *pl = [Player node];

[self addChild:pl];
```

Did you try to call you class like that `[self addChild:pl];` instead of `[self addChild:pl.player];` ?